# Problem with the KeypressEvent of a TableView

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt5

I have a form with a TableView and a function that handles refreshing buttons for adding and removing data in the table etc.

I want to update the states of actions in contextmenu:
I can with the mouse events (tableWidget.clicked) but not with the KeyPressEvent (Up and Down)
I tried with the table keyPressEvent event, but for some reason the keys no longer work.
How to intercept the up and down keys of the table to update buttons for example.

here after an extract of the code :

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QModelIndex, QVariant, QAbstractItemModel, QEvent
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QKeyEvent
import numpy as np
from modules import *

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setObjectName("MainWindow")

        self.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1024, 860))
        self.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(2400, 1024))
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);")
        self.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonIconOnly)
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.retranslateUi()
        self.connectActions()

        self.tableWidget.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.context_menu_Show)

    def bpuHadChanged(self, changed=False):
        self.bpuChanged = changed
        self.actionSave.setEnabled(changed)

    def saveFile(self):
        # TODO
        self.actionSave.setEnabled(False)

    def setBPU(self, bpu):
        self.bpu = bpu
        self.model = TableModel(self.bpu, bpuNewLine)
        self.tableWidget.setModel(self.model)
        self.tableWidget.resizeColumnToContents(0)
        self.updateActionsStates()

    def connectActions(self):
        self.actionNew.triggered.connect(self.newFile)
        self.actionQuit.triggered.connect(self.quit)
        self.actionAdd_une_ligne_bordereau.triggered.connect(self.addLine)
        self.actionRemoveSelectedLine.triggered.connect(self.RemoveLigne)
        self.actionInsertLine.triggered.connect(self.insertLine)
        self.actionSave.triggered.connect(self.saveFile)

        self.tableWidget.clicked.connect(self.updateActionsStates)

        # TODO add connections for up et down actions

    def context_menu_Show(self):
        self.updateActionsStates()
        cursor = QtGui.QCursor()
        self.contextMenu.exec_(cursor.pos())
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.setBPU(bpu)
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Please, read the link in the previous comment. Your code **must** be both minimal **and** reproducible.